# Rotate dynamically created object only if it exists?

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

In the code below, I get an error (as expected) on line 7:

> The name "cube" does not exist in the current context.

```
1. if (action == "place") {
2.     GameObject cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
3.     cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5F, 0);
4. } else if (action == "rotate") {
5.     var x = Convert.ToInt32(message.Args["rotatex"]);
6.     var y = Convert.ToInt32(message.Args["rotatey"]);
7.     cube.transform.Rotate(x,y,0);
8. }
```

This is just for a proof of concept. I won't need to handle multiple cubes like this.  So how should I instantiate it in the proper context (above this `if` statement) without "placing" it in the scene?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should declare the object first, and only rotate it if the value is not `null`. Something like this

```
GameObject cube = null;

if (action == "place") {
    cube = GameObject.CreatePrimitive(PrimitiveType.Cube);
    cube.transform.position = new Vector3(0, 0.5F, 0);
} else if (action == "rotate") {
    var x = Convert.ToInt32(message.Args["rotatex"]);
    var y = Convert.ToInt32(message.Args["rotatey"]);
    if(cube != null)
        cube.transform.Rotate(x,y,0);
}
```

Comment: In this code, cube will always be null in the "rotate" branch so the call to Rotate() could never occur. You would need to instantiate it in the "rotate" branch or somewhere after it is declared but before the if statement.

Comment: Bryan, it is implied (or should be) that the cube will be placed before it is rotated...

Comment: @Matt L.: This still throws an error in the IDE.  Should I just ignore it?  I think idealy I would instantiate the cube above the `if` statement but not "place" it in the scene. Is that possible?

Comment: @RatherNotsay What you are describing is just declaring a variable. There are other work arounds, like a more comprehensive check so that you only enter the "rotate" action if a gameobject exists. Although if you want help with that, we would need to see more code. I'm being pretty naive with this since I don't know the rest of your code, but my best advice would be don't enter the rotate action if the gameobject does not exist

Comment: Sorry, deleted that last comment.  Somehow I had missed the first line in your answer.  I added `public GameObject cube;` to the class and modified the instantiation, everything is great now.

Answer (score 1):

You aren't declaring the cube in your 'else if' statement only your 'if' statement. So in your 'else if' it is referencing something that doesn't exist under that condition.

You can simply use a switch instead.

```
switch (action){
case 'place' :
//Declare Cube (Including Instantiate)
//Do what you want with Cube
break; 
case 'rotate':
//Declare Cube (Including Instantiate) 
//Do whatever else 
break; 
}
```

Comment: This is going to instantiate a new cube every single time I try to rotate "the" cube, no?

Comment: Yes, I misunderstood the question. The solution then is to declare a gameobject variable at the top of the page with your other declares. Then if null or if empty, do the code but don't Instantiate, else Instantiate. If you'd like the proper code, just say and I'll post a new answer.